# Tensorflow use pretrained model in offline

Tags: tensorflow, supervisord, transfer-learning

I'm using mobilenet from Tensorflow with below code.
When I run this code from my local pc, it downloads the weight file.
However, I can not download this online when is uploaded to server.

1. Is there any way I can use MobileNetV2 with tensorflow 2.0.
2. Or, I have my own weight file trained with MobielNetV2, then is it possible to use below without weights option

   mobilenet = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                                                  include_top=False,
                                                                  weights='imagenet')
3. And I want to use supervisord from linux server.
   It seems I need to use absolute path not relative path.
   Could anyone help me to use MobileNetV2 with supervisord in offline environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first use:

```
mobilenet = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

Then save the weights somewhere:

```
mobilenet.save_weights('somefolder/mobilenetweights.h5')
```

Then when you're offline, you could first call:

```
mobilenet = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights=None)
```

Notice the `None` in `weights` argument. After that, you could load the weights from your file, where you saved previously:

```
mobilenet.load_weights('somefolder/mobilenetweights.h5')
```

This should work.

When you call the mobilenet model, if you ask it to give you imagenet weights by using `weights='imagenet'`, it requires internet connection to download those weights. So it won't work offline. The method explained here should get it working.

Comment: Thanks, 1 more question. 
If I have my own weight called abc.h5
Then can I use like this from first time? (i mean it is no need to download Tensorflow imagenet weight?)

mobilenet = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights=None)
mobilenet.load_weights('somefolder/mobilenetweights.h5')

Comment: Yes, if you have saved the weights using the same model, you can use it to load the weights back from your abc.h5 file.